# Calcultating $d\alpha$ with $\alpha$ a $1$-differential form

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let the open interval $J=]0,1[ \in \mathbb{R}$

Let the $1$-differential form: $\alpha = (\dfrac{log(x)}{1-y} - \dfrac{log(1-x)}{y})dy \in \Omega^1(J^2)$

Let $x,y \in \Omega^2(J^2)$ be the coordinate functions

**I am trying to find $d\alpha$** :

$d\alpha$

$= d \Big ( (\dfrac{log(x)}{1-y} - \dfrac{log(1-x)}{y})dy \Big)$

$= d \Big ( \dfrac{log(x)}{1-y}dy - \dfrac{log(1-x)}{y}dy \Big)$ *(I don't   know if I can apply distributivity)*

$= d\dfrac{log(x)}{1-y}dy + \dfrac{log(x)}{1-y}d(dy) - d\dfrac{log(1-x)}{y}dy - \dfrac{log(1-x)}{y}d(dy)$

$ = d\dfrac{log(x)}{1-y}dy - d\dfrac{log(1-x)}{y}dy$ *(because $d\circ d = 0$)*

$= \dfrac{\partial \dfrac{log(x)}{1-y}}{\partial x} dx \wedge dy -  \dfrac{\partial \dfrac{log(1-x)}{y}}{\partial x} dx\wedge dy$ *once again because $(dy)^2=0$*

Now I want to know if that result is right but I have a feeling it's not.

Comment: First, it's not associativity, it's distributivity. Second, your computation is correct but incomplete: go ahead and compute the differentials of those fractions! (Compute only the partial derivatives with respect to $x$, because the ones with respect to $y$ won't be necessary since $\Bbb d y \wedge \Bbb d y = 0$.)

Comment: @AlexM. Here i've edited my post

Comment: It's `\partial`, not `\delta`. And it's correct, but you'll have to explicitly compute those partial derivatives.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for the Latex tip

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ (smooth) then if you have $\alpha  = f dy$:

$$d \alpha = df \wedge dy = (f_x \ dx + f_y \ dy) \wedge dy = f_x \ dx\wedge dy + f_y \ \underbrace{(dy \wedge dy)}_{= 0} = f_x \ dx \wedge dy$$

You just have to compute:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\log(x)}{1-y} - \frac{\log(1-x)}{y}\right)$$

Comment: I've edited my post, I believe it's correct now

Comment: The last line looks fine, but notice that you didn't have to separate the expression in the beginning since you already know differentiation is a linear operation.